# WiFi congestion scanner

Tags: wifi

I would like to know what device or app I can use to scan for WiFi congestion across multiple networks (ideally an Android/IOS app)

For example let us say in my (UK) household I can see 10 SSIDs

Channel1: OneA, OneB, OneC, Me 
Channel6: TwoA, TwoB, TwoC 
Channel11: ThreeA, ThreeB, ThreeC

So in terms of interference no one channel is better than any other on the face of it. From personal experience I just happen to know that "OneC" is a real network hog. They bittorrent all day long really congesting the channel. Whenever I see I share a channel with them I manually move my network to another, and all my data starts flowing normally again.

What I would like is a way to scan for how much congestion each SSID is causing on each channel and to see that information for myself.